# Collision Detection for a Matplotlib graph within Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, collision-detection

I've been creating a physics projectile simulation for my computer science project, and one of the key elements of it is collision detection. Essentially, I need the program to flag up when the "projectile" has hit a certain point.

As an example, if I were to plot a simple line graph like
ax1.plot([0,1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1])
What sort of function would be able to determine if the line produced by the graph passes through the point (3.5,1.5)?

Currently, the code is simply determining the distance travelled by the projectile in the x and y direction each second, so I don't believe a form of estimation can be used, though I may be wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The answer is "yes!". But maybe you want to ask a different question here?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I was also meant to ask how to do it? I couldn't find anything on the internet for it

Comment: What is meant here is that the actual problem is not clear. In addition mind that you cannot expect anyone to write some complete code for you. So you need to add the code you have used to attempt a solution and clearly explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I suppose I essentially need to know how to retrieve information from a graph, so I can then compare it to a preset value. I'm not expecting a complete solution, that would be stupid of me, but I was hoping for some sort of lead.  Apologies that I didn't make the problem clear, though. It's my first time posting

Comment: It's not even clear what information you need. As I see it, none, since if you know the projectile's momentum you just calculate where it hits. As you see, you need to be more specific here. Also, don't apologize, just  [edit] your question to make it clear, that is show the code sample you use to define the projectile and show at which point you need help.

Comment: I've tried to make the point a bit clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have nothing to do with plotting anything. Interpolating the points on the target `x=3.5` would allow you to compare to the target's y coordinate.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.array([5,4,3,2,1,0])

p=(3.5,1.5)
if np.abs(p[1] - np.interp(p[0],x,y)) < 1e-15:
    print "hit"
else:
    print "miss"
```

Note that ideally one would of course compare `p[1] == np.interp(p[0],x,y)`, but to allow for slight numeric inaccuracies the shown solution is more robust.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I just assumed it would have to be done through the graph.